# Find Shortests Paths Without the Heaviest Edge

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have been trying to solve the following problem for some time, without any progress:

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$ and a weight function $w:E \rightarrow \mathbb R_{\geq0}$, for a path $p = v_1\rightarrow v_2 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow v_k$  we define $w^*(p)$ like so: $$w^*(p) = \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}w(v_i,v_{i+1}) - \max\{w(v_i,v_{i+1})|1\leq i<k\} $$
Suggest an algorithm that given a graph $G$, a weight function $w$ and a vertex $s\in V$ finds for each $v\in V$ the shortest path from $s$ to $v$ according to the $w^*$ weight definition. The algorithm should run in $O(V + E\log V)$ time.

First of all, I translated the question to English so I hope it's clear. We've learned both Dijkstra's Algorithm and the Bellman-Ford Algorithm, and according to the time complexity requirements, I assume I should use Dijkstra's Algorithm. I think that I can somehow modify Dijkstra's Algorithm to make it work for this problem, but I believe it would be better if I found a way to modify the Graph in such a way that would allow me to use the "regular" Dijkstra's Algorithm and get the correct result (because the proof of correctness would be much easier this way). However, I'm having a hard time figuring out just what modifications I should apply to the graph.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, I would suggest using the Floyd-Warshall algorithm. The Floyd-Warshall algorithm is a dynamic programming algorithm with a run time of $\Theta(n^3)$. For each iteration in the outer-most loop, the 2D-matrix representing the graph is modified. When initializing the matrix with the weight of each edge, you could use the formula you presented.

I case you insist on using Dijkstra's algorithm, you could modify the *RELAX* method from his algorithm presented below:

[image]

The *RELAX* pseudocode is seen below:

[image]

I would re-define the weight function *w* to be defined as the one you presented.
Also, given we don't know the heaviest edge, computing this in the beginning of the algorithm and saving the value would be beneficial to ensure the run time still would be $\Theta(Elog_2(V))$. Computing this can be achieved with a run time of $\Theta(E)$.